# SAS attach excel last modified date to imported table

Tags: sas, timestamp, import-from-excel

I was trying to import excel to sas grid and add the last modified timestamp for the file into the table.

Referred to the [sas support](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/mcrolref/n1wyzhuyjmwfsun1iwqnluezhql9.htm) I was able to retrieve the last modified time. But I am having trouble with add the time as a new column into the table.

I got this error:

```
SYMBOLGEN: Macro Variable LASTMODIFIED resolves to 09May2023:16:33:19
NOTE: LINE generated by the macro variable "LASTMODIFIED"
282   09May2023:16:33:19
      ----------
       22
       76

ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: !, !!....
ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.
```

Here is the code I tried:

```
%macro FileAttribs(filename);           
  %local rc fid fidc ModifyDT; 
  %let rc=%sysfunc(filename(onefile,&filename)); 
  %let fid=%sysfunc(fopen(&onefile));
     %if &fid ne 0 %then %do;      
  %let ModifyDT=%sysfunc(finfo(&fid,Last Modified));    
  %let fidc=%sysfunc(fclose(&fid));    
  %let rc=%sysfunc(filename(onefile));    
  %put NOTE- Last modified &modifydt;

  proc sql;
  create table work.final as
  select *, &modifydt. as lastmodified
  from work.tb; --the imported table from excel

     %end;
        %else %put &filename could not be open.;
%mend FileAttribs;
```

Also tried to cast the variable to different datatype but also failed.

Comment: "&modifydt."dt as lastmodified format=datetime20.

Comment: This code will only work on Unix as the FINFO() function on Windows is not able to get the 'Last Modified' metadata about a file.

Answer (score 1):

The macro variable is a text string which confuses SQL. Add double quotes and the letters DT to tell SAS you want this to be interpreted as a datetime. Double quotes are for the macro variable to resolve. [More information on date constants can be found here.](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/lrcon/9.4/p0cq7f0icfjr8vn19vyunwmmsl7m.htm#:%7E:text=A%20SAS%20constant%20is%20a,Constants%20are%20also%20called%20literals%20.)

```
"&modifydt."dt as lastmodified format=datetime20.
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! Can’t believe it takes me 2 hours to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you go to all the trouble to put the value into a macro variable if you needed it in a dataset?  Instead of using %SYSFUNC() so you can call SAS functions with macro code just use a data step so you can call the functions directly.

```
%macro FileAttribs(filename);   
%local found;
%let found=0;

filename onefile "&filename" ;
data lastmodified;
  fid = fopen('onefile');
  if fid then do;
    lastmodified = input(finfo(fid,'Last Modified'),datetime19.);
    call symputx('found','1');
    put 'NOTE: FILENAME=' "'&filename'" lastmodified= ;
    fid=fclose(fid);
  end;
  else put 'WARNING: FILENAME=' "'&filename'" ' not found.';
  format lastmodified datetime19.;
  drop fid ;
run;
filename onefile ;

%if &found %then %do;
data work.final;
  set work.tb ;
  if _n_=1 then set lastmodified;
run;
%end;
%mend FileAttribs;
```

Note: This code will only work on Unix as the FINFO() function on Windows is not able to get the 'Last Modified' metadata about a file.